# OpenSSL oracle padding vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107)

Tags: vulnerability, oracle

Hi We have a Windows 2008R2 SP1 server system running Oacle with OpenSSL.
Upon doing a security scan we have found out that we are getting:
OpenSSL oracle padding vulnerability(CVE-2016-2107) vulnerability.

Threat: A MITM attacker can use a padding oracle attack to decrypt traffic.
Impact: A MITM attacker can use a padding oracle attack to decrypt traffic when the connection uses an AES CBC cipher and the server support AES-NI.

What steps on the Windows side can we take to remediate this issue?

Answer (score 2):

A 'padding oracle attack' has nothing to do with the Oracle database software.

Ensure windows is updated, and remove the insecure cipher suites that this machine was configured to use.

Comment: So this vulnerability isn't related to OpenSSL and is OS related? (Windows in this case?)

Comment: @gsb005 all implementations of TLS that use these insecure cipher suites are affected.  SSL/TLS misconfigurations are common because people just assume that software is 'secure' out of the box.